# excel vba with access won't close on this code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Hi I justed posted a few minutes ago and somone asnwerd my question about excel not closing.  I am using access to open a sheet and add a table.  Excel won't close which causes issues down the road as when I get the excel object again in another function the sheet I am working with won't open and it won't format it.  Here is my code.  I thought I was explicit here but maybe I am not.  Excel just won't closed.

```
Public Function BrooksFormatTableBrooks()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

bfile = "S:\_Reports\Brooks\Tyco-Brooks Receiving Tracking MASTER - "

MyFileName = bfile & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xls"

On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MyFileName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

wb.Sheets(1).Name = "RSSR_List"

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

xlApp.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$F$312"), , xlYes).Name = _
     "RSSR"

ws.Range("A1:F312").Select
DoEvents

ws.Cells.Rows("2:2").Select
xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

ws.Columns("A:Z").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ws.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True
ws.Rows("1:1").Font.ColorIndex = 1
ws.Rows("1:1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
ws.Cells.Font.Name = "Calbri"
ws.Cells.Font.Size = 8
ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ws.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

xlApp.Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
xlApp.Cells.Borders.Weight = xlThin
xlApp.Cells.Borders.ColorIndex = 0

ws.Cells.Rows("1:1").Select

wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.Save
wb.CheckCompatibility = True
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

xlApp.Quit

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
MsgBox "Table Add"
End Function
```

Comment: As I said in a comment on the other question, qualify your "Range".   `Range("$A$1:$F$312")` should be `ws.Range("$A$1:$F$312")` rather than defaulting to `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$312")`

Comment: It is very likely that the `xlApp` is displaying some alert or prompt and gets blocked, (notice you are working with an old xls format, in compatibility mode) but since the app is not visible you cannot see what's happening with it. Try adding `xlApp.Visible = True` to observe what is happening. It is possible that `xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False` would solve the issue, with leaving `wb.CheckCompatibility = False`.But let us observe what is happening first.

Comment: @A.S.H - FWIW, I tested the code in this question in Access, and the unqualified `Range` does force Excel to remain active, and qualifying the `Range` allows it close correctly.

Comment: @A.S.H - Oops - no - my test was with a "xlsx" file.

Comment: @YowE3K qualifying the range will improve things, but not sure it is the source of the problem here. Besides, how unqualified `Range` passed compilation in the context of MS-Access VBA beats me.

Comment: @A.S.H - If the project includes a Reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library, the `Range` will be recognised as an Excel Range method, but will  create an extra reference to the Excel Application object - so it doesn't get destroyed at the end.  (Excel will disappear from Task Manager only once all the references to it are destroyed - which will be after `Set ws = Nothing` if the `Range` is qualified as `ws.Range`.)

Comment: Yes I realize OP is using early binding. `"CreateObject" misleaded me.` Okay, so did you make sure that without qualifying that range Excel wont close? (with a normal xlsx) I wont test it for now but if so then your answer will deserve an strong upvote because at least it solves an issue in the question.

Comment: @A.S.H FWIW - confirmed same behaviour with a xls file (i.e. that qualified range closes Excel, unqualified leaves it open).  But there is always the possibility that my xls file still didn't generate the same warning messages that the OP's xls file might generate, so the idea of some undisplayed message may still be valid.

Comment: Another possibility is an error is generated but your handles skips or suppresses it (ill-advised). Have your [error handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193267.aspx) raise a message.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Range("$A$1:$F$312")` with `ws.Range("$A$1:$F$312")` or else you will still have a reference to an Excel Application object that won't be destroyed until you exit MSAccess.

Comment: That behavior of VBA is strange though, because the unnamed range variable evaporates within the sub, so why is a reference maintained because of it, is just ......... an unbelievable anomaly to say the least.

Comment: @A.S.H Possibly a bug?  But also possibly because it is the Access application itself which is being forced to hold the reference to the Range.  (I've given up trying to make sense of why VBA does what VBA does.)

Comment: @A.S.H: It's not a bug. It's just that you have to be _extremely_ specific using objects in Excel VBA when you use automation. You'll learn it the hard way, as the macro recorder of Excel won't educate you, and you can get away with code like this within Excel. But not using automation as here.

Comment: @Gustav the rules of COM is that an object is released when you dont maintain any reference on it. The fact that a *temporary and unnamed* variable causes a permanent reference on the xlApp, like here, is a bug.

Comment: Yes, you and I can mean that; it just doesn't work that way in Excel VBA and never had - since Excel 95/97 - and probably never will. So adopt - _resistance is futile._